# php pdo namespace fatal error in class extend

Tags: php, pdo

I created connection class that returns pdo connection object. Other model classes extend that class. In view mode, I try to get output using namespace and autoload class, but it occur some fatal error 'call to a member function query() on a non-object' . Help me to solve this.

This is Connection.php

```
namespace myproject;
use PDO;

class Connection
{

    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $pass = "";
    private $dbname = "mydb";
    public $dbh;
    private $error;


    public function __construct()
    {

        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;

        try{
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass);
            $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $this->dbh;
        }
        // Catch any errors
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I extend this class to other class 
Form.php

```
namespace myproject;
use myproject\Connection;

class Form extends Connection
{
    public function GetUser($id)
    {
        $sql = "select * from users where uid='$id'";
        $query = $this->dbh->query($sql);
        $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $uname = $data[first_name]." ".$data[last_name];
        return $uname;  
    }
}
```

In front-end page, it came error message I pointed out above.

```
namespace myproject;
include 'Form.php';
include 'Connection.php';

$test = new Form();
echo $test->GetUser(1);
```

Comment: You need to create a object of your parent class connection $obj then call it $obj->$dbh->query($sql);

Comment: @Ravi Hirani : thanks for response, I try it in constructor in From.php, but still error.

Comment: how do you know that there was a success connection with the PDO? you are catching the error under $this->error and not checking it..

Comment: Note that you cannot return anything from a constructor.

Comment: @Yair.R : All these code working when in Form.php file including the Connection.php without using namespace.

Comment: I'm talking about  $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass); did it really created or there was an exception and went to the error

Comment: Note that [your class will kill a database server](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#connection).

Comment: in your Form class, you can also create a constructor, which basically only initiates the parent class' constructor. Like this: class Form extends Connnection { function __construct(){ parent::__construct() } }. If you create a new instance of Form right now, the parent class' constructor is never called, thus $this->dbh is null

Comment: Thanks all, @YourCommonSense: thanks for that article..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Form.php** file should be:-

```
namespace myproject;
use PDO;  // add this line

class Form extends Connection{
    public function GetUser($id)
    {
        $sql = "select * from users where uid='$id'";
        $query = $this->dbh->query($sql);
        $data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // added single quotes around first_name and last_name
        $uname = $data['first_name']." ".$data['last_name']; // added single quotes around first_name and last_name
        return $uname;  
    }
}
```

Your **View** file should be:-

```
<?php
namespace myproject;
include 'Connection.php'; // include connection file first
include 'Form.php'; // include form file second

$test = new Form();
echo $test->GetUser(1);
```

Hope it will help you :-)